# Javascript blank screen error

Tags: javascript, html, web, minecraft

I am setting up a website for my Minecraft server and I ran into this problem, I followed the instructions, as seen in the link below, and it doesn’t work, nothing shows up, it is just blank.

Image URL:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/jAqkI.png

This is the code that I am doing:

```
<script src="http://www.playgrid.com/api/2.0/js/f87087296b71a8c31eccf14d8b809982f5158662/" type="text/javascript" async=true ></script>
<div class="playgrid-recent-players">
    <!-- widget will be inserted here -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like JQuery is required for this widget to run, try including it above the widget code:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Here is a working fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/p7PjS/